# Fabric JS Clip Itext object with the path inside svg

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a project that involves using Fabric.js to manipulate SVG elements on a canvas. I have successfully loaded an SVG onto the canvas, which contains a specific path with an ID named "placeholder_front." Now, I need to add a text box inside this "placeholder_front" boundary, ensuring that the text is only visible within the confines of the path and hidden outside of it.

Approach:

Initially, I attempted to use the clipPath property of fabric.IText to clip the text to the "placeholder_front" path. However, this approach didn't work as expected, and the text became invisible.

Next, I tried to use a custom mask with a transparent rectangle placed over the text. This solution also didn't produce the desired result, and the text remained fully visible.

Can some one guide, how could it be done?

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/7cLqsor9/

```html
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");

fabric.loadSVGFromURL("https://images.printify.com/api/catalog/627ced4234f16f9fa50cef31.svg", (objects, options) => {
    const svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    // Adjust the SVG size to fit the canvas
    const scaleFactor = Math.min(
      canvas.width / svg.width,
      canvas.height / svg.height
    );
    svg.scale(scaleFactor);

    // Center the SVG on the canvas
    svg.left = (canvas.width - svg.width * scaleFactor) / 2;
    svg.top = (canvas.height - svg.height * scaleFactor) / 2;

    canvas.add(svg);

    // Find the "placeholder_front" box within the SVG
    const placeholderBox = svg._objects.find(
      (obj) => obj.id === "placeholder_front"
    );

    if (placeholderBox) {
      // Calculate the position and dimensions of the "placeholder_front" box
      const boxLeft = placeholderBox.left * scaleFactor + svg.left;
      const boxTop = placeholderBox.top * scaleFactor + svg.top;
      const boxWidth = placeholderBox.width * scaleFactor;
      const boxHeight = placeholderBox.height * scaleFactor;

      // Create a fabric.IText object
      const text = new fabric.IText("Your Text Here", {
        fontFamily: "Arial",
        fontSize: 12,
        fill: "black", // Set the text color
      });

      // Set the position of the IText object to be centered inside the "placeholder_front" box
      const transformMatrix = placeholderBox.calcTransformMatrix();
      const center = fabric.util.transformPoint(
        { x: boxLeft + boxWidth / 2, y: boxTop + boxHeight / 2 },
        transformMatrix
      );

      const textLeft = center.x - text.width / 2;
      const textTop = center.y - text.height / 2;

      text.set({ left: textLeft, top: textTop });

      text.center();
      canvas.add(text);

      // Update the canvas
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
);
```